# IIS web app is not accessible on the same network but Apache app is

Tags: asp.net, apache, iis, networking, server

I have a server that has both Apache and IIS running simultaneously.
Both apps are configured on different ports and both apps use HTTPS.
The app on Apache (port 433) is accessible on any computer on the network, but I can't get the IIS app (port 4433) to work.
 It says: **This site can’t be reached**
I can ping the server. 
I'm trying to access both websites with IP address of the server and port after it. 
The IIS app works on the server, both with localhost address and server IP address.

I have tried all the solutions I found:
 1. disabling firewall
 2. allowing just the port I needed through the firewall
 3. allowing anonymous access in IIS
 4. different ports (4433, 7200...)

Nothing seems to work.
I will be grateful for any help.

Comment: If you're getting a 404, assuming you're hitting the proper site, then the problem isn't in the networking layer. The problem is your app. Either you're requesting a file that doesn't exist, or your routes are incorrect in your server side code.

Comment: @mason sorry it's not 404 then, It's just not accessible

Comment: the site works on the server itself so the app should be fine

Answer (score 1):

I assume your IIS binding looks something like this:

[image: IIS Bindings]

Specifically, "All Unassigned" for the IP address, and no host name defined.

If that is what you have, then it sounds like a firewall problem. i.e. The traffic is not reaching your server.

The easiest way to check this is to turn off Apache and change the IIS binding to use port 443. If it works, then you know it's just the other port that doesn't work.

You can also use something like [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) to actually see if any traffic on port 4433 is making it to your server (you can use the filter `tcp.port == 4433`). If you don't see any traffic there even though you've made a request from another computer, then something is blocking it.

And when I say "firewall", I don't mean Windows Firewall. I mean either a router or dedicated firewall appliance that would need to be configured to allow traffic to that port.

Comment: Thank you, I have tried both bindings, "All unassigned" and the server IP address, I got the same results, so do you think that the only solution to this is configuring some network hardware like router?